# How to disable MaterialPickerRenderer from changing underline opacity in Xamarin.Forms Material Visual

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, material-design

I have created a custom renderer to extend the [MaterialPickerRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual/material-visual) that is available in Xamarin.Forms.

The default behavior for the **MaterialPickerRenderer** is to render an opaque *underline* (see image below).

[image]

In my custom renderer, I am trying to disable this behavior - I do not want the underline to be opaque. In my custom renderer for iOS, I have been able to set the initial underline color, however, the color is updated to an opaque color when the picker loses focus (see gif below).

[image]

I am only focusing on the renderer for iOS at the moment. I wondering if anyone has any suggestions about how to override and disable this default MaterialPickerRenderer behavior. Below is my custom renderer code:

```
using System;
using Foundation;
using Solstice.Extensions;
using Solstice.iOS.Renderers;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Material.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Picker), typeof(TitledMaterialPickerRenderer), new[] { typeof(CustomVisual) })]
namespace Solstice.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class TitledMaterialPickerRenderer : MaterialPickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Underline.Color = UIColor.Clear.FromHex(0x46433E);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class UIColorExtensions
    {
        public static UIColor FromHex(this UIColor color, int hexValue)
        {
            return UIColor.FromRGB(
                (((float)((hexValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)) / 255.0f),
                (((float)((hexValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)) / 255.0f),
                (((float)(hexValue & 0xFF)) / 255.0f)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciate - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `Control.Underline.Layer.BorderColor` instead:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Picker), typeof(TitledMaterialPickerRenderer), new[] { typeof(VisualMarker.MaterialVisual) })]
namespace VisualDemos.iOS
{
    public class TitledMaterialPickerRenderer : MaterialPickerRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Underline.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHex(0x46433E).CGColor;
                Control.Underline.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class UIColorExtensions
    {
        public static UIColor FromHex(this UIColor color, int hexValue)
        {
            return UIColor.FromRGB(
                (((float)((hexValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)) / 255.0f),
                (((float)((hexValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)) / 255.0f),
                (((float)(hexValue & 0xFF)) / 255.0f)
            );
        }
    }
}
```